# Not able to get the result in Mongodb query

Tags: php, mongodb

All,

I have written a php query to get the details from Wikisrch database in mongodb and collection is dailymotion.

Below is my php code.

```
<?php

$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB('wikisrch');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'dailymotion');

// search for fruits
$fruitQuery = array('tags' => 'news');
echo 'connecting';
$cursor = $collection->find($fruitQuery);
var_dump($db->lastError());
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}

?>
```

THis is my result 
connectingarray(4) { ["n"]=> int(0) ["connectionId"]=> int(3) ["err"]=> NULL ["ok"]=> float(1) }

But I'm not able to get the record output in this query.

Any guess on how to get the data from table. This is my first php - mango code.

Comment: Edit your question to show some of the data you are querying. As a hint your dump of `getLastError` information shows **n: 0** which means no results where found.

Comment: Thanks for all your response. Found the issue. It is having 2 issues. One with driver and other with the return records.